# How to limit producers from emitting events with property's existing value?

Tags: ios, reactive-swift

Does setting the value of a MutableProperty result in the producer emitting a new event with the same value?

In other words, if I don't want new events with the same value, do I need to do this != check?

```
let really = MutableProperty<Bool>(false)

func updateReality(newReality: Bool) {
    if really.value != newReality {
        really.value = newReality
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties always send the new value, even if it's the same as the old value. It has to be this way or else you couldn't use it with non-`Equatable` types. But if you are dealing with an `Equatable` type, like `Bool`, then you can use the [`skipRepeats` operator](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift/blob/c56fa134c0d39b82dcc10b27c38632af4d96be10/Sources/Property.swift#L177) on your property to create a new property that only receives new values, and then expose that property to consumers:

```
let really = MutableProperty<Bool>(false)
let reallyWithNoRepeats = really.skipRepeats()
```

So you would update the value via `really.value`, but consumers subscribe to `reallyWithNoRepeats` to get new values only.